# Errors linking to tdh.lib

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio-2019, etw

I'm trying to use functions from the Microsoft TDH library building with Visual Studio 2019. The project is using `WindowsApplicationForDrivers10.0` *Platform Toolset* and the program is very simple:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <tdh.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "tdh.lib")
int __cdecl wmain(_In_ int argc, _In_ wchar_t* argv[]) {
    ::TdhCloseDecodingHandle(nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

When building the program I'm getting the following error:

> Build started...
>
> 1>------ Build started: Project: main, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
>
> 1>Building 'main' with toolset 'WindowsApplicationForDrivers10.0' and
> the 'Universal' target platform.
>
> 1>main.cpp
>
> 1>main.vcxproj -> C:\Play\wpp\cpp\x64\Debug\main.exe
>
> 1>ApiValidation : error : main.exe has unsupported API call to
> "tdh.dll!TdhCloseDecodingHandle"
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.common.targets(1794,5): error MSB3721: The
> command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\ApiValidator.exe"
> -DriverPackagePath:C:\Play\wpp\cpp\ctrl..\x64\Debug\main.exe -SupportedApiXmlFiles:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\universalDDIs\x64\UniversalDDIs.xml"
> -ModuleWhiteListXmlFiles:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\universalDDIs\x64\ModuleWhiteList.xml"
> -ApiExtractorExePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64"" exited with code -1.
>
> 1>Done building project "main.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Does anyone know what the problem is, or how to prevent `ApiValidator.exe` from running as part of the build?

Thanks in advance,

-Uri

Comment: If conditions permit, you could try to set Platform Toolset to visual studio.

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT Unfortunately, doing this disables WPP trace macros which is the whole reason to use `WindowsApplicationForDrivers10.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the Visual Studio settings:[image: ApiValidator]